# Get Value of two values in observableArray using Knockout/Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm wondering how I can take two values out of an observableArray and divide them to get a percentage value. I'm trying to divide defectsCompleted/defectsTotal to return a percentage value.

This is what I have, but it's not working. Can anyone assist?

```
function userProfileVM() {
var self = this;

self.userprofile = ko.observableArray([
    { name: 'Bert Bertington', minutesComplete: '284', minutesTotal: '480', defectsCompleted: '254', defectTotal: '546' },
    { name: 'Charles Charlesforth', minutesComplete: '298', minutesTotal: '480', defectsCompleted: '236', defectTotal: '677' },
    { name: 'Denise Dentiste', minutesComplete: '242', minutesTotal: '480', defectsCompleted: '542', defectTotal: '854' }

    //Having issues with this part
self.progressWidth = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.userprofile.defectsCompleted() / self.userprofile.defectTotal() + '%';
}, self);

}

ko.applyBindings(new userProfileVM());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mujaji/Lxec4quj/13/

Comment: You have multiple "profiles"... which one are you trying to calculate for?

Comment: trying to calculate defectsCompleted / defectsTotal

Comment: self.userprofile is an (observable) array. You're accessing it like a plain object to pull defectsCompleted.

Comment: how do I divide those two values (defectsCompleted/defectsTotal) to get a new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to introduce another viewModel

```
function UserProfile(name, minutesComplete, minutesTotal, defectsCompleted, defectTotal) {
    this.name = name;
    this.minutesComplete = minutesComplete;
    this.minutesTotal = minutesTotal;
    this.defectsCompleted = defectsCompleted;
    this.defectTotal = defectTotal;

    this.progressWidth = ko.computed(function(){
        return this.defectsCompleted / this.defectTotal + '%';
    }, this);
}


function MainViewModel() {
    this.userprofiles = ko.observableArray([
        new UserProfile('Bert Bertington', 284, 480, 254, 546),
        new UserProfile('Charles Charlesforth', 298, 480, 236, 677),
        new UserProfile('Denise Dentiste', 242, 480, 542, 854)
        ]);
}

ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
```

Comment: Something is wrong with your `progress` binding, because it works without it, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxec4quj/17/)